# Function Type Restrictions

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Is it generally preferable to have the strictest or loosest type definition for a function?  What are the pros and cons of each approach?  I found that when I rewrote [my pearson correlation code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155662/pearson-correlation-in-haskell) using strictly doubles, it was easier for me to write, follow, and reason about (this could just be inexperience).  But I can also see how having a more broad type definition would make the functions more generally applicable.  Would stricter type definitions be characterized as a form of tech debt?

With Typeclasses:

```
import Data.List

mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
mean xs = s / n
    where
        (s , n) = foldl' k (0,0) xs
        k (s, n) x = s `seq` n `seq` (s + x, n + 1)

covariance :: Fractional a => [a] -> [a] -> a
covariance xs ys = mean productXY
  where
   productXY = zipWith (*) [x - mx | x <- xs] [y - my | y <- ys]
   mx        = mean xs
   my        = mean ys

stddev :: Floating a => [a] -> a
stddev xs = sqrt (covariance xs xs)

pearson :: RealFloat a => [a] -> [a] -> a
pearson x y = fifthRound $ covariance x y / (stddev x * stddev y)

pearsonMatrix :: RealFloat a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
pearsonMatrix (x:xs) = [pearson x y | y <- x:xs]:(pearsonMatrix xs)
pearsonMatrix [] = []

fifthRound :: RealFrac a => a -> a
fifthRound x = (/100000) $ fromIntegral $ round (x * 100000)
```

With Doubles:

```
import Data.List

mean :: [Double] -> Double
mean xs = s / n
    where
        (s , n) = foldl' k (0,0) xs
        k (s, n) x = s `seq` n `seq` (s + x, n + 1)

covariance :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance xs ys = mean productXY
  where
   productXY = zipWith (*) [x - mx | x <- xs] [y - my | y <- ys]
   mx        = mean xs
   my        = mean ys

stddev :: [Double] -> Double
stddev xs = sqrt (covariance xs xs)

pearson :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
pearson x y = fifthRound (covariance x y / (stddev x * stddev y))

pearsonMatrix :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]]
pearsonMatrix (x:xs) = [pearson x y | y <- x:xs]:(pearsonMatrix xs)
pearsonMatrix [] = []

fifthRound :: Double -> Double
fifthRound x = (/100000) $ fromIntegral $ round (x * 100000)
```

Answer (score 8):

*Readability* is a matter of opinion. In general, I find that more general type signatures are more readable because there are fewer possible definitions (sometimes there is even only one non-diverging definition). For example, seeing that `mean` only has a `Fractional` constraint immediately limits the operations being performed in that function (compared to the `Double` version which could be performing `sqrt` operations for all I know). Of course, generalizing types [is not always](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html) [more readable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:ito). ([And just for fun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6UbD.png))

The main disadvantage of having more general versions of functions is that they may remain unoptimized at runtime so that `Double`'s dictionary of the `Floating` functions has to be passed to `mean` every time it is called.

You can have the best of all worlds by adding a [`SPECIALIZE` pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-pragma). This tells the compiler to basically duplicate your function code with some of the type variables instantiated. If you know you are going to be calling your `mean` function pretty much only with `Double`, then this is what I would do

```
{-# SPECIALIZE mean :: [Double] -> Double #-}
mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
mean xs = s / n
  where
    (s , n) = foldl' k (0,0) xs
    k (s, n) x = s `seq` n `seq` (s + x, n + 1)
```

And you get to see the specialized version of the signature in your code too! Yay!

Comment: Right, though sometimes the most general polymorphic signature is just a bit too crazy. If the constraint list alone is twice as long than the full specialised type would be, I'd think about it whether this is really sensible. (Though `ConstraintKind`-`type`defs can make such signatures quite a bit more readable, this comes at a price of obscurity in error messages etc..)